# Cheap polarized sunglasses, good or bad?

Tags: eye

Im currently located in Thailand and bought very cheap (for less than 10$) but *polarized* sunglasses.
Will I do good or bad to my eyes, wearing the sunglasses in the sun?
In other words, how much protection does the polarization give?

Answer (score -1):

Quality is not always dependent on actual price and vice versa. Trust famous brands and some glasses have characteristics written.